# Fancybox and custom script

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have a link

```
<a href='#detail_form' class='btn fancybox detail'> Details...</a>
```

And form

```
<form id="detail_form" class="hidden">
...
</form>
```

This my script to handle click a#detail_form. It works correctly

```
$(".detail").on('click', function() {
                var self = $(this).parent().parent();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'details',
                    data: {id: self.children("input").attr("value")}
                }).done(function(data) {
                    if (data=="true")
                    {
                        var a = self.children("a").children("span");
                        a.html(parseInt(a.html())+1);

                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
```

Also I call fancybox

```
$(".fancybox.detail").fancybox({
        width: 600,
        autoDimensions: true,
        fitToView : false,
        scrolling : 'no'
    });
```

When I clicked a#detail_form, my script is starting, but fancybox doesn't respond.

Comment: and why it must respond? where is the relations between tham?

Comment: My link has a class 'fancybox detail' and it refers on form by id. $(".fancybox.detail").fancybox({}); this code calls fancybox. and if i remove my custom script, fancybox works correctly.

Comment: try to set `$(".fancybox.detail").fancybox({});` after `a.html(parseInt(a.html())+1);` maybe you are looking for it

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work too.